# How to link two tables from SQL Server Database to a SharePoint List?

Tags: sql

How can I link two tables from an External SQL server database to a SharePoint list and also send emails from it.

Comment: Could you add more details about what you mean regarding "send emails from it?" Are you talking about alerts or work flow or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an External List (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/04/27/walkthrough-of-creating-a-sharepoint-2010-external-list-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx). But if you are talking about making it email enabled (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/Video/ff679958) I think it's not supported for external lists.

Comment: Thx for the links but the article does not explain how to link tables after creating External Database.

Comment: You can then create a lookup columns in your list that links to your external lists